# Extract tables and exporting them to excel with different sheets looping

Tags: python

How do you loop links from one excel document and extract the tables within using python, then exporting them to another excel document using a loop to create multiple sheets and placing each table in each sheet respectively?

I have figured out creating multiple sheets in excel using a loop, but I cannot figure out a code on how to loop an excel sheet with multiple links and extracting all the tables within and placing them into the sheets in of the other excel.

```
from pandas import Series, ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter('Sheet.xlsx')

for counter in range(0,11):
    sheet_name = 'Sheet%s' % counter'
    Series(name = '').to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

writer.save()
```

I expect the output to have multiple sheets created in excel with all the tables places within each excel sheet.

Comment: Hello Kevin, welcome to Stackoverflow. I think you should add an example of the source excel sheet and an example of the corresponding output you expect.

Comment: @jottbe, thanks for responding. An example of the source excel sheet would be 20 website links such as these ones: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000104746907003054/a2177242zdef14a.htm
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/6201/000095013408006896/d53442def14a.htm

So you could place these two links into column A of an excel file. I have over 10,000 links just to let you know. The expected output I want is to be able to web scrape the tables within those websites (specific ones if possible, if not then whole) and export them to a new excel file with each table in a sheet.